# How to get Sum() of all the input fields which id start from same string

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I have very simple and clear question. i have dynamically created input fields with:

```
id=pend_1, id=pend_2 .....id=pend_14
```

i need to get Sum() of all the input fields which id starts from **pend_*** ?

for more clarity, please see the figure:

[image]

is there any easiest way to get sum() of all the input fields?

In this scenario, users will put values in the text fields and jquery will calculate the sum() with onBlur() event...

Comment: use `$('[id^=”text”]')` to select all the id that starts with same text

Comment: You can have same `.class` for such inputs and then use `$.each` to iterate and sum each of them

Comment: @SandeepNayak i appreciate you idea...i would like to test this.

Comment: @SandeepNayak, no need of .each() function as we have get() and reduce(), `get() ` will return an array and method `reduce()` reduces the array to a single value., I have answered below please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you add single class to all of those fields such as

< input type="text" class="sum_item" id="pend_1"  />

< input type="text" class="sum_item" id="pend_2" />

And use following code to sum them up

```
var sum=0;
$('.sum_item').each(function(){
 var item_val=parseFloat($(this).val());
 if(isNaN(item_val)){
  item_val=0;
 }
 sum+=item_val;
 $('#total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: your solution is little resource hungry but it a fantastic solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume there are number of Divs with `id="test_1", id="test_2"` etc..., you can get the count using the following method

```
var count = ($("div[id^='test']").length
```

For taking the sum you have to write the Anonymous function which takes the result and element as the parameter As @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy mentioned the solution is correct,

But a small change if a input type has NaN Value then convert it to 0 here is the code with slight modification., you can use `||` operator in this case to return 0 by default if the value is NaN for eg. `let a = $('#a').val() || 0;`

```
var sum = $("input[id^='test'][type='text']")
              .get()
              .reduce((res, elm) =>  
                        (res + (+elm.value || 0)), 0);
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: @RajaPrabhu AravindaSamy, just a small suggestion, add || Operator with value 0 which will return 0 while adding up, as this will give the result of integer values instead of returning NaN .

Comment: Good point. But I thought, suggesting a basic idea to the asker would let him to write his entire requirement on his own.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy I just checked with a string to only one input type and the entire sum returned null, so i tried with this solution.

Comment: @Reiah Paul Sam Your code is awesome... i will pick the idea for my other problem in which is solution is really comes very fit.

Answer (score 1):

`​$("[id^=AAA_][id$=_BBB]")`
It will return all the elements that matches all the specified attribute filters:

- `[id^=AAA_] matches elements with id attribute starting with AAA_,` and
- `[id$=_BBB] matches elements with id attribute ending with _BBB.`

Hope this helps.

Comment: let me check this solution with my problem. i hope it work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can get it by using the following code,

```
let sum = $("input[id^='pend_'][type='text']").get()
              .reduce((res, elm) =>  (res + (+elm.value)), 0);
```

use a `starts with selector` and then `get()` the array representation of the elements, then `reduce` it to a sum.

Comment: This is very simple solution if work, let me try this too after the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input[id^="pend_"][type="text"]').on('input',function(){
var sum = 0;
$('input[id^="pend_"][type="text"]').each(function(){
var valu = $(this).val() == '' ? 0 : $(this).val();
if(!isNaN(valu))
{
sum = sum + parseFloat(valu);
}
});

$('label').text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pend_1" ><br/>
<input type="text" id="pend_2" ><br/>
<input type="text" id="pend_3" ><br/>
<input type="text" id="pend_4" ><br/>
<input type="text" id="pend_5" ><br/>
Result:<label id="result" value="label"> </label>
```